# How do I get a reference to the UITableView in the view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an app that displays a list of products that can be purchased. The view controller for the list looks like this:

```
@interface InAppPurchaseListUIItemViewController :
UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    IBOutlet UITableView *_inAppPurchaseListTable;
.
.
.
}
.
.
.
@end
```

This is the code that displays the list:

```
_inAppPurchaseListUIItemViewController = [[InAppPurchaseListUIItemViewController alloc]
    initWithItemList:   [[InAppPurchaseManager getInstance] getAuthorisedInAppPurchaseProducts]
    :                   self
    andSelector:        @selector(inAppPurchaseSelected:)
];

_inAppPurchaseListCustomUIView= [[InAppPurchaseListCustomUIView alloc]
    initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, inapp_purchase_table_width, inapp_purchase_table_height)];

[_inAppPurchaseListCustomUIView addSubview:_inAppPurchaseListUIItemViewController.view];
_inAppPurchaseListUIItemViewController.view.frame = _inAppPurchaseListCustomUIView.frame;
```

`InAppPurchaseListCustomUIView` subclasses `UIView` and is otherwise an empty class.

There is also an .xib with the same name as the view controller. The .xib seems to contain a Table View and nothing else.

The list displays fine, but now I want to change the items displayed. I have an `NSMutableArray` backing the table. When I change the array, I need to get the `UITableView` to redraw with the new array, but `_inAppPurchaseListTable` is allways nil.

- How do I get a reference to the UITableView so I can call `reloadData`?
- Is there anyway I can get rid of the .xib? I don't see the point of an extra file that does nothing but hold a table view.

Connections Inspector 
[image]

Comment: Did you connect `_inAppPurchaseListTable` with the xib file!?

Comment: In the .xib, using the Connections Inspector, what outlets do you have linked to the table view?  ...especially in the "Referencing Outlets" section?  Also, what does the initWithItemList: method look like?

Comment: @Scar, how do I do that?

Comment: @Phillip, I attached a screen shot.

Comment: Why are you not just using a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @Nic, No idea. I did not write this code.

Comment: drag the new referencing outlet to the files owner, it will appear the view instance and the tableview instance, connect it to the table view.

Comment: Usually there would be a referencing outlet but since you say that the starting list displays OK, there's something else going on here that's not obvious from what you've posted.  Again, I think the initWithItemList: method may have clues.

Comment: @Scar, I've tried that already, it doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out finally. The answer is on page 43 of the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableView_iPhone.pdf).

I need to add this to the view controller:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc]
        initWithFrame:  [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]
        style:          UITableViewStylePlain
    ];

    tableView.autoresizingMask = 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];
    self.view = tableView;
    [tableView release];
}
```

Then I deleted the .xib, and the IBOutlet in the view controller.

Now I can reload the table view with `[tableView reloadData];`. And I don't need an .xib.

Comment: Yeah, don't use .xib or IB if you don't have to. It makes things more difficult.